# Efficient algorithm to found duplicated values

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, performance-testing

I'm practice some algorithms lessons at Codility, and i'm now at [that lesson](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/2-arrays/odd_occurrences_in_array)

To resolve that, I created the algorithm as follow:

```
A = [9,3,9,3,9,7,9]
for index, item in enumerate(A):
    counter = A.count(item)
    if(counter == 1):
        output = item
        print(output)
```

The algorithm works as well, but he is not performatic... I get just 25% of efficient and I will appreciate opinions about how can I make that code better?

I guess that he count each index can make it not-performatic... any suggestion to improve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `collections.Counter()`.

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate` here? Note that `index` isn't used in the body of the loop. The problem with you code is that `A.count(item)` sweeps over the whole list for each item, making your algorithm quadratic in complexity. The suggestion of @Barmar will get it down to linear.

Comment: @Barmar did you have any example to show me?

Comment: Did you read the linked question? It has 36 examples.

Comment: @JohnColeman yeah I get it... thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Barmar ? yes of course I did...

Comment: Then what's the problem? I'm not going to repeat the examples here.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I thought you are talking about the lesson of codility, not the stackoverflow link ;) my bad, I will take a look, and thank you for your attention